# Google Jam 2018 Senate Evacuation

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I was trying to solve the Problem "Senate Evacuation" of the 2018 Google Code Jam Practice Round (Can't place the word code in the title :/) (https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000000130/00000000000004c0). See the link for a description of the problem.

My approach was to sort the parties and then always remove one senetor of the party with the highest number of senetors. In order to still know which letter correspond to which number I pair them up before sorting. Then I create a pointer l, that is the index before which every party has the most senetors. For example for the parties [4,4,4,2,1], l=2 because the parties with the index 0,1 and 2 have the most senetors. I then always remove one senetor from all parties with index smaller or equal to l. To avoid having only one senetor left at the end, which would mean that he had an absolute majority, I always remove the last two parties with the most senetors at once. So for the example above, I would first remove a senetor from the party with index 0, then remove a senetor from party 1 and 2 at the same time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;

    string alph = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for(int t=0; t<T; t++) {
        int N;
        cin >> N;
        vector<pair<int, char>> part;
        for (int n=0; n<N; n++) {
            int num;
            cin >> num;
            part.push_back(pair<int, char>(num, alph[n]));
        }

        sort(part.begin(), part.end(), greater <>());

        cout << "Case #" << t+1 << ": ";

        int l = 0;
        while (l<part.size()) {
            while (l<part.size() && part[l].first <= part[l+1].first) {
                l++;
            }
            for (int i=0; i<=l; i++) {
                if (part[i].first > 0) {
                    part[i].first--;
                    cout << part[i].second;
                    if (i+1 != l && part[part.size()-1].first != 0) {
                        cout << " ";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

For the test cases all works out perfectly, but the submission still gets me a wrong anwser response and I just can't figure out what input would break my code.

Test input:

```
5
2
10 10
3
3 2 2
3
1 1 2
3
2 3 1
5
3 3 3 3 10
```

Output:

```
Case #1: BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA BA
Case #2: A A CB A CB
Case #3: C C BA
Case #4: B BA B AC
Case #5: E E E E E E E E D C BA E D C BA E D C BA
```

Comment: `while (l<part.size() && part[l].first <= part[l+1].first)` -- What happens if `l == part.size() - 1`?  That is an illegal access when `part[l+1]` is executed..  Also, it helps to use meaningful names instead of one-letter names such as `l`.

Comment: To prove my point, [here is your program using the first test data](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a96131848727dda7), and `at()` is used instead of `[ ]` to access the elements (with the addition of cleaning up the type being used in the loop).  Note the `std::out_of_range` exception.  So your code doesn't really work for any of the test cases.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the two while statement of code worked.
Thanks to @PaulMcKenziw for pointing out the mistake.

```
while (l<part.size() && part[part.size()-1].first != 0) {
    while (l<part.size()-1 && part[l].first <= part[l+1].first) {
```